# Convert a BIGINT to a string inside a JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, replace

I am trying to convert a quote number to a string, inside a JSON.stringify()

The number is behaving like a BIGINT so it cannot be changed after parsing

When parsed as an INT the number `950375379233915148` turns into `950375379233915100`

```
let json=  "[{\"IDItem\":1111111,\"ItemName\":\"Test\",\"startDate\":\"Aug 31 2020 12:00AM\",\"FinishtDate\":\"Aug 31 2020 12:00AM\",\"startTime\":\"10:30:00.0000000\",\"itemNum\":123564554,\"Place\":\"10\",\"IDItemType\":30,\"Remark\":null,\"SmooveId\":0,\"WebinarKey\":950375379233915148,\"FullDescription\":null,\"ItmCode\":\"TE\",\"isPublic\":false,\"ActiveUserID\":1}]"
```

Trying to replace by regex:

```
json.replace(/WebinarKey":(\d.+),/, "WebinarKey\":\"$1\",")
```

That's what I get:

```
"[{
"IDItem":1111111,
"ItemName":"Test",
"startDate":"Aug 31 2020 12:00AM",
"FinishtDate":"Aug 31 2020 12:00AM",
"startTime":"10:30:00.0000000",
"itemNum":123564554,
"Place":"10",
"IDItemType":30,
"Remark":null,
"SmooveId":0,
"WebinarKey":"950375379233915148,"FullDescription":null,"ItmCode":"TE","isPublic":false",
"ActiveUserID":1
}]"
```

The replace function converts the string of all variables starting from `"WebinarKey"` to `"isPublic"` i.e. it adds the quote after `false"`

and I just want to convert the variable "WebinarKey" content to string

Comment: Try `(\d+)` instead of `(\d.+)`. *Note* This is not a recommended way

Comment: @Liam if I convert the json into an object, the number that is in the WebinarKey would change to something like this "3669516009270899000" because it is a BigInt, that is why I need to convert it to a string before converting it to an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BEST solution is to make the producers of this JSON fix their string

To solve your RegEx issue, you need to make the regex  [lazy instead of greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

So `(\d.+?),` or `(\d+?),` instead of `(\d.+),`

```js
let json=  "[{\"IDItem\":1111111,\"ItemName\":\"Test\",\"startDate\":\"Aug 31 2020 12:00AM\",\"FinishtDate\":\"Aug 31 2020 12:00AM\",\"startTime\":\"10:30:00.0000000\",\"itemNum\":123564554,\"Place\":\"10\",\"IDItemType\":30,\"Remark\":null,\"SmooveId\":0,\"WebinarKey\":950375379233915148,\"FullDescription\":null,\"ItmCode\":\"TE\",\"isPublic\":false,\"ActiveUserID\":1}]"

let changed = json.replace(/WebinarKey":(\d.+?),/, 'WebinarKey":"$1",')
console.log(JSON.parse(changed))

// if only numbers in the field

changed = json.replace(/WebinarKey":(\d+?),/, 'WebinarKey":"$1",')
console.log(JSON.parse(changed))
```